# Sending a encrypted JSON through AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

Im migrating from AFNetworking`1 to`AFNetworking 2.0.`

I have to send an encrypted `JSON`, before we just sent a `NSSTring`, but now we send a `NSDictionary` as the `JSON to POST.`
I've been looking and I can't find how to do the same thing for the 2.0 version.

this is the previous code:

```
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"url: %@", url);

    NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:
                         [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                                           error:nil]
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", jsonStr);

    NSData *requestData =  [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//[NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonStr UTF8String] length:[jsonStr length]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonStr length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:[self sha256:jsonStr] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Hash"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:USERNAME password:PASSWORD persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {

 }
```

I would like to find the same functionality on `AFNetworking 2.0..`
As you can see I add a `X-Hash` header and I send a encrypted version of the `JSON` with a sha256 function.

Thanks.

Comment: SHA256, in fact any hash function, is **not** encryption.

Comment: You sure? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2, SHA-2 is a set of cryptographic hash functions

Comment: Yes, this isn't encryption.

Comment: What's not working with this code in AFNetworking 2?

Comment: after encrypting are you able to get the data back??

Comment: @subharb Yes, they are cryptographic hash functions and are not encryption. Neither is a cryptographic random number generator. Wait, let me check with my CISSP cryptographer ... OK, they are not encryption. :-)  What really concerns me is developers who know basically nothing about cryptographic security creating products that use it, they are rarely secure. If one cares about security one needs to have the security designed by a security domain expert or at least verified by one--if one really wants security.

Comment: It's maybe because english is not my native language but I still don't see why is wrong the title of my question.
@AaronBrager the method setAuthenticationChallengeBlock is deprecated on AFNetworking 2.0

Comment: @Zaph Totally agree! I'd like to add that it's a sign of professionalism & maturity to acknowledge this is a non-expert.

Comment: @subharb The problem with the title is the words "encrypted JSON" because there is no encryption, the JSON is being sent un-encrypted. A hash (SHA256) is being sent which is OK but I can see no reason to send it and that is not encryption.

Comment: You may be right, but what does this do then [request setValue:[self sha256:jsonStr] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Hash"];
From what I know the request is sending a plain JSON and an encrypted JSON, the server will handle both and do what is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"login" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
[operation setCredential:credential];
```